# Multiple 'IN' clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem with a SQL query. I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM serie WHERE serie_id IN
 (SELECT serie_id FROM L WHERE L_value = 33 AND I_value >= 0,1)
 AND serie_id IN (SELECT serie_id FROM clusterserie WHERE cluster_id LIKE 'RF%') ;
```

I would like use 2 IN clauses in this query, because I have to check that the field serie_id fulfil that 2 requirements.
Anyone knows what is wrong in this query?
thanks and best regards!

Comment: Did you get an error when you executed the query?  What was it?

Comment: I see a problem here: `AND I_value >= 0,1`...unless that's just something that I've never heard of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try joining the subqueries like below

```
SELECT b.* FROM serie b
inner join L a on (a.serie_id = b.serie_id)
inner join clusterserie c on (c.serie_id = b.serie_id) 
WHERE c.cluster_id LIKE 'RF%'
AND a.L_value = 33 AND a.I_value >= 0
```

Comment: What does this do in MySQL: `a.I_value >= 0,1`?  I'm unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: I'd do `SELECT b.* ...` as it seems OP only wants data from `serie` in the result. +1: joins are better than subqueries (imho).

Comment: sorry i just copied your query above so left the >= 0,1 in there, i have set it to >= 0 as 1 > 0 so there is no need for the 1 to be there

Comment: This works perfectly! the problem now is understand why and try to export to other querys... Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error here:

```
AND I_value >= 0,1)
```

Not sure what that is supposed to mean.

Also, your query would benefit greatly from avoiding subselects and instead using joins:

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    serie s
    INNER JOIN L
        ON s.serie_id = L.serie_id
    INNER JOIN clusterserie cs
        ON s.serie_id = cs.serie_id
WHERE
    L.L_value = 33
    AND L.I_value >= 0 /* or whatever this is supposed to be */
    AND cs.cluster_id LIKE 'RF%'
```